# importing Wikipedia api giving a error (python)

Tags: python

I am having a error with importing the Wikipedia API for python. This is the [quickstart](https://wikipedia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#quickstart) and I am doing everything correctly, but I am getting a error:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'wikipedia'
```

Code:
`import wikipedia`

I have installed Wikipedia through command prompt, as I am getting an error:

```
Requirement already satisfied: wikipedia
```

Comment: See if you get the name of module `wikipedia` when you run `help("modules")` in IDLE

Comment: Yes, I do, in fact, the basic code found on the quickstart also works. Is there a reason why VSCode does not want to import/run this?

Comment: make sure you are installing the package in the Python environment you are using to run the code. E.g. it is often the case that `pip install x` should be changed to `pip3 install x` if you intend to use Python3.x (and vice versa). Even better, if you run a script with `python script.py`, you can do `python -m pip install x`

Comment: So, is it that the module works with IDLE but not with VSCode?

Comment: I am guessing, but this website says:
"If you are using any IDE such as Microsoft Visual Studio Code, PyCharm and even Sublime Text then make sure in the terminal you enter the below command"